# How to display pageaction icon on specific website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is my `manifest.json`, just in case for reference.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "Results app",   "description": "This extension helps
 calculate your total and percentage.",   "version": "1.0",

"permissions": ["http://www.example.com/*"],

 "page_action": {
      "default_icon": {                   
        "19": "icon.jpg"

      },
      "default_title": "",     
      "default_popup": "popup.html"      
    },

 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"]
  }
 ]
}
```

How do I get `pageaction` icon to be displayed on the site which matches the criteria as given in manifest.json.

I tried [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-extensions/47hx1yoM04c/discussion) but no avail.

Generally, now how can I get `pageaction` icon to be displayed??

**Debugging background page:** I got this error
[image: Debugging background page]

Comment: Regarding the edit: Have you added `declarativeContent` to the permissions section of your manifest file? It's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to show the page action button (since Chromium 33) is via the [`chrome.declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API:

For example, to show the page action on `example.com` and its subdomains, the following code can be used:

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: {
                        hostSuffix: 'example.com'
                    }
                })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
});
```

Do not forget to add the `declarativeContent` and `*://*.example.com/` permissions to your manifest file.

See the documentation of the [`UrlFilter` type](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter) for more ways of matching URLs, and [`chrome.declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) for usage details.

Comment: Hii @Rob W , where should this code be used be used, on contentscript.js or background.js. I'm bit confused, can u let me know?

Comment: @nikhil background.js

Comment: I'm getting an error when I'm debugging the background page.I attached the image of the error, what's wrong with that?I'd be glad to know.Thanks!

Comment: @nikhil Have you added `"declarativeContent"` to the permissions section of your [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) file?

Comment: @nikhil Read the documentation: [declare permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions).